# Apache FOP float text right

Tags: html, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Im using the Apache FOP to convert Html document to PDF.
In my document I need the right align. I was using http://webcoder.info/downloads/xhtml2fo.xsl stylesheet but the float feature is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>W22</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p style= "float: right">
          Invoice No : $invoiceId  <br>
          Date : $date  <br>
          Client Ref : $customerAccount  <br>
          Email : $email
      </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your subject lines talks about "right align"ing text, yet your XHTML uses CSS to float right which is something different in my view. Furthermore the stylesheet you have used does not make any attempt to "transform" any CSS in the XHTML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Thanks, updated the heading. Is there a specific xhtml2fo.xsl sheet we can use for this? or do we need to right xsl sheet from scratch for this?

Comment: It seems FO supports https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e14346 and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#float, only Apache FOP has, depending on the version, no or only limited support http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#floats. As for generic XHTML to PDF or XHTML to FO stylesheet taking CSS into account, I don't know, oXygen for instance has built-in transformation scenarios for XHTML to Dita and the Dita to PDF but I am not sure about the CSS support.

Comment: cloudformatter.com has an XSL at it's heart that handles a lot of inline CSS styles in changing CSS style attributes to XSL FO. You could look into that XSL for conversion but it is specific to handling one or more div's from a live browser.